# if post id matches these id's then do this

Tags: php, single

I'm still a noob with php but I'm trying to display a different layout for my Wordpress webpage for a single post id.

I thought it would have been simple but I've tried a quiet few variations of the code below. Including `is_singular` and without the `$post` etc. and I've ran out of inspiration. What can I do? What do I need to look for? Can anyone help me out?

```
<?php

if (is_single ($post = '2578')) {
    get_template_part('partials/content', 'challenge');
} 
elseif (is_single ($post = ''))  {
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'challenge-2');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'categories');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'snake-checklist');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'timeline'); 
}?>
```

Answer (score 11):

This looks almost correct. Let's have a look at [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/):

> Works for any post type, **except attachments and pages**...

So if the given ID isn't that of a `page` or `attachment` post type then you can use the function as so:

```
if( is_single( 2578 ) ) {
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

Otherwise, if the ID is a `page` post type you can use [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

```
if( is_page( 2578 ) ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Should the ID be that of an `attachment` page you may use [`is_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_attachment/)

```
if( is_attachment( 2578 ) ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Finally, if you're unsure of the post type you could check against the `global $post` object, assuming it is correct:

```
global $post;
if( is_object( $post ) && 2578 == $post->ID ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The function `get_the_ID()` will work regardless of post type (if it's a page, post, or custom post).

You could use that function to perform your conditional check.

```
if ( get_the_ID() === 2578) {
     get_template_part('partials/content', 'challenge');
} 
else{
    // Add other template calls, or additional conditions, is_single, is_archive, etc.
}?>
```

Noting that this function won't work on archives since they don't have ID's.

Comment: This is the most universally effective method and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if( $post->ID == 21) { ?>
    <?php include('file_1.php'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php include('file_2.php'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this answer is correct?

Comment: it kind of works, but it’s too much `<?php` and `?>`